# PHP - Is operator order LTR or RTL?

Tags: php, operators

If I have a conditional statement

```
if (A > B || B > C)
```

Which statement is going to be evaluated first: "A > B" or "B > C"?

Does same order is applied to math statements:

```
$var = $value1 + $value2 + $value3;
```

Thanks,
Alex.

Comment: It's left to right unless operator precedence is specified by using parenthesis. Then those are evaluated first and then normal evaluation from left to right is performed.

Comment: LTR. with lazy evaluation.... A > B will be evaluated first, and if true it won't even bother evaluating B > C because it's an OR condition

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php < PHP operator precedence and associativity

Comment: As Mark said, that is why something like `mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die("could not connect");` works

Answer (score 1):

In PHP the script is evaluated from left to right unless parenthesis are used, if they are used it evalutes then in logical order. In addition please remember that no code in the if condition block(including evaluators) are ran past the first failing statement. This example will only execute the second echo $a and it's value will be 0

```
$a = 0;

if(1 == 0 && $a = 5)
{
    echo $a;
}
echo $a;
```

This statement will have $a value of 5 and will execute the statement. Interestingly, the reason that the code will execute is because the $a = 5 assignment  in the if sets $a = 5 or " 5 = 5".

```
if(1 == 1 && $a = 5)
{
    echo $a;
}
```

Also note there are else and else if statements if you have not looked into it

```
$a =2
if($a == 2)
{

}
else if($a > 2){
  echo ">".$a;
}
else{
   echo "its none of the conditions";
}
```

The reason that you use two equals signs is to compare the value type insensitive vs one equal which would be assigning the value. There is also three equals which would compare the type and value example This would evaluate to true :

```
$a = 2;
if($a == "2")
```

The following would not be true because you are comparing a String to integer.

```
$a = 2;
if($a === "2")
```

Regarding your second questions the same is true of String operators but your syntax is INVALID.

This Example  Would say Hellow World:

```
echo "hellow"."world";
```

This Example IS NOT DOING CONCATENATION(Though it would do addition if they are integers)

```
echo "hellow" + "world";
```

Comment: Interestingly, the reason that the code will execute is because the $a = 5 assignment in the if sets $a = 5 or "5 = 5".

This is really interesting how it works because assignemnt operator has lowest priority.

So in the statement

>>>if(1 == 1 && $a = 5)
== is evaluated first as it has highest priority
but next should be "&&" or am I missing something?

Comment: the if statement evaluates each statement in order the && is essentially a join between statements, scripting languages tend to evalutate things in the order that they occur to the parser

Comment: I wanted to say following. In assignment statement, for example $res = $var1 + var2, "+" is evaluated first and then assignement because it has lower priority. But what will happen when using assignment inside if-statement, e.g. if (3 > 2 && $var = 10). According to precedence ">" is evaluated first because it has higher priority than "&&" and "=". Then "&&" should be evaluated because it has higher priority than "=" but it looks really strange. Am  I missing something?